# Angular "change" output propagates input event implicitly

Tags: angular

I'm facing a strange behavior, I have a simple component that wrap a text input:

```
export class InplaceInputComponent {
  @Input() value: string;
  @Output() change = new EventEmitter<string>();

  editedValue: string;

  inputChange(event: any) {
    this.editedValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
  }

  ok() {
    this.change.emit(this.editedValue);
  }

  cancel() {
    this.editedValue = this.value;
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<input
  type="text"
  [value]="value"
  (change)="inputChange($any($event))"
  [style]="'padding: 5px; border: 1px solid blue;'"
/>
<button type="button" (click)="ok()">OK</button>
<button type="button" (click)="cancel()">Cancel</button>
```

Parent component:

```
<inplace-input [value]="name" (change)="onNameChange($any($event))"></inplace-input>
```

If I modify input and click "cancel", the parent component receives the "change" event, even if the EventEmitter wasn't called. If I change the @Output from "change" to "textChange", this weird behaviour stops. Can you explain me why, and what are the "reserved words" for custom components events?

Steps to reproduce: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-muspg2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

1. change text input
2. click "cancel"
3. you can see the received event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing a native HTML behaviour here. Actually, your `HTMLInput` element is located in an internal component and emits `change` events with ability to bubbling. So, to solve this simple problem you have to rename your `Output` from the `change` event to any other, or I would prefer to stop bubbling the change event explicitly.

Like this:

```
<input
  type="text"
  [value]="value"
  (change)="inputChange($any($event)); $event.stopPropagation()"
  [style]="'padding: 5px; border: 1px solid blue;'"
/>
<button type="button" (click)="ok()">OK</button>
<button type="button" (click)="cancel()">Cancel</button>
```

Comment: correct, I thought the event was fired by the button click, but it's fired when input loses focus

Comment: yes, it's native input `change` behaviour, works even on focus events